# How to find TEMP tablespace usage?

Tags: oracle, temp, tablespace

we are using v$sort_segment to calculate temp file usage. but one of my temp tablespace not available in v$sort_segment table. IS there any other way to get the correct usage which returns the same value as in v$sort_segment?

Answer (score 2):

V$SORT_SEGMENT only gets populated as a temporary segment is required.  For example, if I create a second temp tablespace, then it does not appear because it is not in use

```
SQL> create temporary tablespace temp2 tempfile 'X:\ORACLE\ORADATA\DB19\PDB1\TEMP02.DBF' size 20m;

Tablespace created.

SQL> select tablespace_name from v$sort_segment;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------
TEMP
```

If you want a view of all of your temporary tablespaces, you can outer join either DBA_TABLESPACES (type=TEMPORARY) or DBA_TEMP_FILES to V$SORT_SEGMENT.

Comment: Hi Connor, Got it. Thank you for the answer. There are multiple views available to get temp usage such as V$TEMP_SPACE_HEADER, V$TEMP_EXTENT_POOL  & v$sort_segment. But all giving different results. Which should be the correct way to get the usage.